# Can I know who have done serial voting to me?

Tags: feature-request, review, up-votes, serial-voting

Yesterday,  I don't know how but i got **up vote** in all  my questions and answer in Mathematics, Physics, Chemistry and Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange. Due to i got total around +310 reputation.

Today that serial voting was revised in Mathematics and Physics S.E. So I want to know which user has done this serial voting, Is it possible?

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: @ShadowWizard I just wanted to know why he did that. You know first getting + reputation and then again taken away is bit irritating.

Comment: @gnat not really a dupe, as the OP here explicitly ask who done it and why, and he does know what it means and how it affects him.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "When does serial _upvoting_ occur?

Most often..., it's just a user trying to give you extra reputation. They saw a post of yours that was extraordinarily helpful to them and they feel that going through your posts systematically and upvoting them is the appropriate way of granting you additional reputation (apparently they've forgotten about the bounty system).

Occasionally, it also occurs between two users who have made an agreement to upvote each other, or between one user and a sock puppet account trying to game the system for extra reputation..."

Comment: @Freddy many people want to know who votes for them, not only when it's serial and the answer is always the same: this information is not accessible and we can't know. Best just to ignore it and move on. :)

Comment: @gnat well, since the answer to the OP's direct question is just "no", guess that other post is the best next thing.

Comment: Nice find @gnat, voted.